# Access iPhone camera from Mobile Safari (iOS8)

Tags: ios, iphone, file-upload, safari, mobile-safari

I build a simple web page that should enable our users to use the camera to upload documents copy.
It works great in android but in iOS mobile safari its only open the image library and doesn't let the user to simple open the camera and take a shot.

I've used that input field:

```
<input style="width:100%" class="upload" id="house" type="file" accept="image/*" capture doc="house" name="files[]" data-url="/api/upload/detail" multiple>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end the solution was simple.
The "***multiple***" attribute should not be present or it will go right to the gallery without giving the user the option to choose the camera.

Nir

Comment: Did you find any way to make it go directly to the camera without presenting the dialog for camera/photo gallery? (asking about iOS). Thanks.

Comment: On Safari/iOS10 even though `multiple` was present I still got the "Take Photo", "Photo Library", "iCloud Drive", etc. options. See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/).